# Two Place Order Button in woocommerce Checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I am having Issue in my checkout page. I am getting Two Place order button([click here](http://www.sweetbabyshop.in/checkout-2/)). I tried to fix it in form-checkout.php even I checked in form-pay.php, in wp-content/themes/mytheme/woocommerce/checkout.

I checked in wordpress forum I got solution to remove two checkout button from cart page, there is no solution for my problem

```html
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $woocommerce;

wc_print_notices();

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', $checkout );

// filter hook for include new pages inside the payment method
$get_checkout_url = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_checkout_url', WC()->cart->get_checkout_url() ); ?>

<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout" action="<?php echo esc_url( $get_checkout_url ); ?>">

 <?php if ( sizeof( $checkout->checkout_fields ) > 0 ) : ?>

  <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details' ); ?>

  <div class="row" id="customer_details">

   <div class="col-md-6">

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_billing' ); ?>

   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6">

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping' ); ?>

   </div>

  </div>

  <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details' ); ?>

  <h3 id="order_review_heading"><?php _e( 'Your order', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>

 <?php endif; ?>

 <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review' ); ?>

</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form' ); ?>
```

Comment: It looks like you're using a premium theme, are you using a version of WooCommerce that's compatible with the theme?

Comment: yes premium Theme is from OPAL,I updated the woocommerce to 2.3.10.I had same issue like this in cart page with two checkout button.  I removed one links from cart.php (solution from wordpress forum). is there any solution like removing some code.

Comment: It looks like the theme is out of date. What shortcode are you using on that page as well?

Comment: I am not sure about shortcode on that page. I have used shoertcode only on Home page, rest are all default.

Comment: Logan thank you for spending time for me. I found the solution.

Comment: Solution is - go to wp-content/themes/mytheme/woocommerce/checkout/view-order.php file I removed <div id="payment">...</div>
As logan said this issue is because of theme version

Answer (score 0):

Go to wp-content/themes/mytheme/woocommerce/checkout/view-order.php. In View-order.php remove id="payment" completle

This issue is because of theme version

Answer (score 0):

Please check your configuration in your WordPress admin. 
Woocommers->settings on the Payment Tab check your information details if you have miss an  HTML tags.

I have experience on this when I customized or add some html tags on the details text area with closing "div" tag.